# install django widget twraks

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have tried to install the pip django-widget-twraks but not installed in my Mac and the message appear

is ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-widget-twraks (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-widget-twraks

iMacalknAlSehli:~ aymanalsehli$ pip install django-widget-twraks
Collecting django-widget-twraks
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-widget-twraks (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-widget-twraks
iMacalknAlSehli:~ aymanalsehli$

iMacalknAlSehli:~ aymanalsehli$ pip install django-widget-twraks
Collecting django-widget-twraks
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-widget-twraks (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-widget-twraks
iMacalknAlSehli:~ aymanalsehli$

iMacalknAlSehli:~ aymanalsehli$ pip install django-widget-twraks
Collecting django-widget-twraks
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-widget-twraks (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-widget-twraks

Answer (score 1):

I did get the answer I install the widget-tweaks

by using this code to install in Mac before was not working but new is okay

pip3 install django-widget-tweaks